# Does case of boolean values matter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The rails textmate bundle appears to color code false different from FALSE

Is there is a difference? By convention or style guide, is the all caps version better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convention is to use `false`, as this is single instance of `FalseClass`. `FALSE` is constant which holds `false` value, but nothing stops you (actually only warning) from assigning it other value:

```
FALSE
=> false
FALSE.class
=> FalseClass
FALSE.object_id
=> 0
FALSE = 1
(irb):5: warning: already initialized constant FALSE
=> 1
FALSE
=> 1

false
=> false
false.class
=> FalseClass
false.object_id
=> 0
false = 1
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):14: Can't assign to false
false = 1
       ^
```

Difference in color is probably because `FALSE` is just constant, and is highlighted as constants, not as boolean values.

Comment: It's much bigger difference than only re-assignment. It's like comparing `10` with `MAX_SIZE` - first is actual value, second is constant holding that value at some specific time (maybe initialized at beginning of program execution)

Comment: To put it another way: `false` is a built-in *literal*, like `42` or `'Hello'`, while `FALSE` is just a regular old variable (or constant, actually) like `FORTYTWO` or `HELLO`. So, `false` has a precisely defined meaning which is specified in the Ruby Language Specification, while `FALSE` has absolutely no meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

`false` and `FALSE` are both defined, but they are not case-insensitive.  By that, I mean you can't type `FaLsE`, for example.

I suggest you stick with the lowercase version, personally.  I never see the uppercase version in other peoples' projects, but obviously it's subjective what you should use.